# C# override object.ToString() in runtime using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, runtime, overriding

I would like to override object.ToString() for struct in runtime using reflection?
I need to change one struct, add new or modify existing override, in some .dll for which I don't have code. So I am thinking to do it in runtime.

Is it possible? Tutorial for this would be excellent?
If answer is NO then: is answer different for class?

Comment: Think of `dynamic proxies` like `Linfu` or `Castle` although I don;t know it it could be applied to structs.

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change the implementation of an existing class or struct using reflection. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be easier to just use an extension method `ToStringNew()`?

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static string ToStringNew(MyStruct str)
    {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

I thought that's what extension methods were designed for...

Comment: No, I don't want to add ToStringNew, I need to change existing ToString.

Comment: Would this answer change if this is class, not struct?